# Filtering rotational acceleration (Appropriate use for Kalman filter?)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, filtering, accelerometer, kalman-filter

I'm working on a project in which a rod is attached at one end to a rotating shaft. So, as the shaft rotates from 0 to ~100 degrees back-and-forth (in the xy plane), so does the rod. I mounted a 3-axis accelerometer at the end of the moving rod, and I measured the distance of the accelerometer from the center of rotation (i.e., the length of the rod) to be about 38 cm. I have collected a lot of data, but I'm in need of help to find the best method to filter it. First, here's a plot of the raw data:

[image: Raw data]

I think the data makes sense: if it's ramping up, then then I think at that point the acceleration should be linearly increasing, and then when it's ramping down, it should linearly decrease. If its moving constantly, the acceleration will be ~zero. Keep in mind though that sometimes the speed changes (is higher) from one "trial" to the other. In this case, there were ~120 "trials" or movements/sweeps, data sampled at 148 Hz.

For filtering, I've tried a low pass filter and then an exponentially decreasing moving average, and both plots weren't too hot. And although I'm not good at interpreting these: here is what I got when coding a power frequency plot:

[image: spectral density]

What I was hoping to get help with here is, attain a really good method by which I can filter this data. The one thing that keeps coming up again time and time again (especially on this site) is the Kalman filter. While there's lots of code online that helps implementing these in MATLAB, I haven't been able to actually understand it that great, and therefore neglect to include my work on it here. So, is a kalman filter appropriate here, for rotational acceleration? If so, can someone help me implement one in matlab and interpret it? Is there something I'm not seeing that may be just as good/better that is relatively simple?

Here's the data I'm talking about. Looking at it more closely/zooming in gives a better appreciation for what's going on in the movement, I think:

http://cl.ly/433B1h3m1L0t?_ga=1.81885205.2093327149.1426657579

Edit: OK, here is the plot of both relavent dimensions collected from the accelerometer. I am neglecting to include the up and down dimension as the accelerometer shows a near constant ~1 G, so I think its safe to say its not capturing much rotational motion. Red is what I believe is the centripetal component, and blue is tangential. I have no idea how to combine them though, which is why I (maybe wrongfully?) ignored it in my post.

[image: two dimensions]

And here is the data for the other dimension:

http://cl.ly/1u133033182V?_ga=1.74069905.2093327149.1426657579

Comment: The data supplied mention the `y` axis of the tri-axial accelerometer. How was this axis compared to the rotation. Is `y` showing the centripetal acceleration (oriented radially), or the tangential acceleration (oriented tangentially) ?

Comment: Thanks for asking that Hoki. That has been something I've been struggling with for a while now. I think it is showing the tangential acceleration, however, the dimension that supposedly gives the centripetal acceleration is curious. The accelerometer is mounted well, but not perfectly. So I think I'm losing some information from the "y dimension" into the "z" dimension, which I had thought to be the centripetal.

Comment: Also, the other dimension usually reads ~1 G (9.8 m/sec^2) constantly, so I am choosing to ignore that. Since the accelerometer rotates with the rod, and does not move up and down, I think I can safely ignore that. Reading online, I am supposed to do some type of vector transformations or use rotational matrices, but I have no idea how to do that so I'm leaving it alone for now. I will update my post with the centripetal component and plot them together to show you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the Kalman filter, see the note at the end of the answer for the reason why.

Using a simple moving average filter (*like I showed you on an earlier reply if i recall*) which is in essence a low-pass filter :

```
n = 30 ; %// length of the filter
kernel = ones(1,n)./n ;
ysm = filter( kernel , 1 , flipud(filter( kernel , 1 , flipud(y) )) ) ; 
%// assuming your data "y" are in COLUMN (otherwise change 'flipud' to 'fliplr')
```

*note: if you have access to the `curvefit` toolbox, you can simply use: `ys = smooth(y,30) ;` to get nearly the same result.*

I get:
[image: accelfull]
which once zoomed look like:
[image: accelfull]

You can play with the parameter `n` to increase or decrease the smoothing.

The gray signal is your original signal. I strongly suspect that the noise spikes you are getting are just due to the vibrations of your rod. (depending on the ratio length/cross section of your rod, you can get significant vibrations at the end of your 38 cm rod. These vibrations will take the shape of oscillations around the main carrier signal, which definitely look like what I am seeing in your signal).

---

Note:
The Kalman filter is way overkill to do a simple filtering of noisy data. Kalman filter is used when you want to calculate a value (a position if I follow your example) based on some noisy measurement, but to refine the calculations, the Kalman filter will also use a prediction of the position based on the previous state (position) and the inertial data (how fast you were rotating for example). For that prediction you need a "model" of the behavior of your system, which you do not seem to have.

In your case, you would need to calculate the acceleration seen by the accelerometer based on the (known or theoretical) rotation speed of the shaft at any point of time, the distance of the accell to the center of rotation, and probably to make it more precise, a dynamic model of the main vibration modes of your rod. Then for each step, compare that to the actual measurement... seems a bit heavy for your case.

Look at the quick figure explaining the Kalman filter process in this wikipedia entry : [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), and read on if you want to understand it more.

Comment: Thank you for the very elaborate response Hoki. One follow up question is that do you think the attenuation that happens with this method is OK? It probably is, but I just wanted to hear your opinion. Also thanks for the explanation about the kalman filter. I don't think I mentioned it in my original post but I actually am collecting position and time data as well, so calculating the velocity isn't hard for me. Perhaps I can investigate the Kalman filter (and see why its so darn popular) in the future as an exercise.

Comment: Oh one more question. I am slightly worried about the offset (from zero) seen in the data. Theoretically, it should be zero no? After talking with some people, it may have to do with the orientation of my accelerometer (its not perfect). Apparently I should use rotation matrices to transform the measurements to a different coordinate system - one where one axis feels an acceleration of g and the rotation of the rod influences another axis only, but I'm unsure of how to do this. Do you think you can help here, or does this warrant a different question?

Comment: @JohnAlberto. It's definitely another question, and it would probably be better on another SO site more related to signal processing. Regarding the attenuation it depends what you are interested in. If you want to monitor the motion of the shaft (low freq) and ignore the vibrations of the rod, then this way is ok. If you want to study the vibrations of the rod, then you need to keep the high frequencies. As for the bias (offset of the zero), a misalignment of ~3degrees of your accel would give you the 0.05G offset in your data... quite possible indeed.

Comment: Whoa how did you calculate that? Did you do that in your head? Crazy. I may go ahead and ask another question related to that offset. Signal processing right?

Answer (score 1):

I will propose for you low-pass filter, but ordinary first-order inertial model instead of Kalman. I designed filter with pass-band till 10 Hz (~~0,1 of your sample frequency). Discrete model has following equation:

```
y[k] = 0.9418*y[k-1] + 0.05824*u[k-1]
```

where u is your measured vector, and y is vector after filtering. This equation starts at sample number 1, so you can just assign 0 to the sample number 0.

Comment: Is there an easy method/function to implement these in matlab? Alternatively, I can probably just iterate through the data and implement your model as a function, right?

Comment: yes, its simply - you already have your vector (u data), then you make loop
`for i=2:length(u)
     y(i) = 0.9418*y(i-1) + 0.05824*u(i-1);
end`
ofcourse, before loop, you need to initialize first sample: `y(1)=0;`

Comment: Thanks Rafal. I think it's really interesting how similar your answer is to Hoki's, but I think I'll go with his. It's very very slight, but the peaks after using Hoki's method align just a little better than yours (it's just a tiny offset). The magnitude is very similar or pretty much the same though. Also, I can see myself using your method in a lot of other applications, so I really appreciate your response. Would +1 again if I could.