# Matlab background removal/ smoothing slider for multiple lines in plot

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, slider, smoothing

I have made a GUI to import and plot multiple (SERS) spectra files, in case you want to see what the code is like here it is:

```
d = uigetdir(pwd, 'Select a folder');
files = dir(fullfile(d, '*.txt'));
len = length(files);
linecolors = jet(len);

for i = 1:len
    a = files(i).name;
    filename{i} = a;
    path = [d, '\', a];
    data = dlmread(path);
    plot(data(:, 1), data(:, 2), 'color', linecolors(i, :), 'linewidth', 2);
    hold on;
end
hold off;
```

These spectra have a broad background and very weak signals. I therefore need a code to intensify these peaks. A typical spectrum looks like this:

[image]

I'm basically looking for a matlab function to go from (a) to (b)...

I have come across freely available MATLAB GUI files for background removal, such as the one here:

http://www.victoria.ac.nz/raman/publis/codes/cobra.aspx

but I don't understand the matlab coding and therfore cannot implement it in my own GUI. I'm wondering if there is an easier in built matlab function which can do this?

In case there are a lot of background peaks I would to include a smoothing function as well. Can anybody suggest a suitable one for smoothing a spectrum such as the one below:

[image]

I would also like to vary the amount of smoothing/ background removal. Would I be able to make a slider for this? Or else allow the user to enter in a number according to how much they want the function to be run?

I'm sorry for asking so many questions but any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: Since the question was regularly revived by successive edits, let's see if the OP is still around. Yes it is possible to vary a parameter with a slider (or other control) and update a plot accordingly. But I do not understand your "_smoothing_" method at all. You first talk about getting the differential between points, and then _**plotting** the gradient_. Plotting a gradient (a derivative) is (1) a new curve, and (2) usually less smooth than the original curve. Please edit your post to explain better your desired "smoothing" method.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit confused with the smoothing method. I had been told that taking the differential between 2 points on the spectra would be a useful code... I realize now that this would be to remove the background rather than smooth the line. Hope my explanation is better now!

Comment: Well, that's much clearer now. It is also two different questions. Regarding the smoothing, a basic way is to do a moving average (low-pass) filtering. An example in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661488/filtering-rotational-acceleration-appropriate-use-for-kalman-filter/29662406#29662406). Regarding the background removal, you can look at the derivative (gradient) indeed to detect sharp changes, but there is no simple method. You should try a few thing by yourself, and also upload a small sample of the signal you want to process.